# A group of order pq with a single subgroup of order p

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Given a group $G$ of order $pq$ (such that $p,q$ are primes and $p < q$) 
that have a single subgroup of order p (named $H$)

prove that  $\forall h \in H , g\in G : ghg^{-1} = h$

Answer (score 1):

First note that $H$ is normal in $G$ since for all $g\in G$, the subgroup $g^{-1}Hg$ has $p$ elements.

Take an element $g\notin H$. If $g$ generates $G$, we are done. Else $g$ has order $q$. Take a generator $h$ of $H$. We want to show first that $gh=hg$.

To see this, consider the operation of $<\!g\!>$ on $H$ by conjugation: $x\mapsto g^{-1}xg$. This gives a homomorphism $<\!g\!>\to \mathrm{Sym}(H)$. But since $q$ does not divide the order of $\mathrm{Sym}(H)$ (which is $p!$), this map is not injective, so it must be the identity.

Hence $gh=hg$. Now $gh$ has order $pq$.

Indeed, if $gh$ has order $p$, then $g^p=1$, which is not possible. On the other hand, if $gh$ has order $q$, then $h^{q-p}=1$, which is not possible.

So we see that $gh$ generates $G$.

Comment: Why does o(gh) = q means that h^q = h^p

Comment: We see that $G$ must be commutative, since $H$ is a normal subgroup and $G/H$ is cyclic. Hence $1=(gh)^q=g^qh^q=h^q$. I will update the answer.

Comment: Who said that it is normal? If you could please show the full proof

Comment: @OferMagen Because $H$ is the unique subgroup of order $p$ it follows necessarily that $H$ is characteristic (hence normal) in $G$.  It is an easy exercise to show that for any group $G$ if $K\leq G$ is the unique subgroup of order $k$ in $G$, then $K$ is fixed by all automorphisms of $G$.

Comment: I updated the answer with a slightly different argument to see that $gh=hg$.

Comment: Even if it is normal (which is easy to show) and that G/H is obviously cyclic how does that tell us that G is commutative?

Comment: my bad, the argument that you ask about works for $H=Z(G)$. I avoided to use this in the answer, where I just show that $gh=hg$.

Comment: Now it is really complicated. I'm sure there is a better way to show that gh = hg

Comment: I've updated the question so it's more clear now

Comment: Is the operation on H or on G?

Comment: on H. It remains in H since H is normal.

Comment: @OferMagen Orlando Marigliano just define a group action of $\langle g\rangle$ on $H$ by $g^r\cdot h=(g^r)^{-1} h (g^r)$.
This group action induce a **homomorphism** (not only be a map) $\theta:\langle g\rangle\to \text{Sym}(H)$. 
Which is given by $\theta(g^r)=\sigma_{g^r}$, $\sigma_{g^r}(h)=(g^r)^{-1} h (g^r)$. 
(This is a normal process in the group action.)
If $\theta$ is injective, 
then $\ker{\theta}=\{e\}$ and by the first isomorphism theorem, 
$\langle g\rangle \cong \langle g\rangle /\ker{\theta}\cong \text{im }\theta\leq \text{Sym}(H)$.

Comment: But $q=|\langle g\rangle|$ doesn't divides $|\text{Sym}(H)|=p!$.
So $\ker{\theta}\neq\{e\}$.
On the other hand, $\ker{\theta}\leq \langle g\rangle$ and $|\langle g\rangle|=q$, 
so $\ker{\theta}=\langle g\rangle$.
Therefore, $\theta(g)=\sigma_g$ is the identity element in $\text{Sym}(H)$.
Then $g^{-1}hg=\sigma_g(h)=h$.

Answer (score 0):

By applying Sylow's 3rd theorem, we conclude that there is exactly one Sylow $p$ and exactly one Sylow $q$ subgroup and hence both of them are normal. Also their intersection is trivial since $p$ and $q$ are two distinct primes. So, $G$ is the direct product of $C_p$ and $C_q$  which is essentially $C_{pq}$

Comment: You shouldn't shoot a fly with a cannon. I'm looking for a much simpler proof

Comment: If you have a cannon and infinitely many bullet, then you will shoot anything by the cannon.